# How is this straightforward question about the need to recompile for different architectures problematic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971895/can-a-program-made-using-intel-processor-run-on-other-processors-without-recompi) is *exactly* the type of question/answer Stack Overflow needs:

> If we compile a C++ program on an Intel processor without using any processor-specific feature, would it run on some other company's processor without recompiling?
> [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/processor)

I see thousands of my-code-doesn't-work "questions" flow through this site, and then something like this, which is an *excellent* question, gets closed?

I am baffled. What are curating users on this site looking for?

Comment: How is it an excellent question?  It's based on a false premise that requires no research effort to come to.  Almost any research on what a compiler does and what machine code is would have shown that C++ is generally compiled into a architecture specific instruction set.

Comment: *"I am baffled by what the moderators on this site are looking for."* As far as [I can tell](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75971895/timeline, no [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) have had any involvement in that question (unless you count [Henry Ecker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker)'s [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/424088/revisions) of *this* question here on Meta).

Comment: But isn't SO the place where people will go to _do_ this research? What percentage of questions asked and answered here can't be answered by researching elsewhere? Why even have this site?

Comment: So what research did you do before you asked that question, @pamphlet ? What about the content you read didn't you understand?

Comment: How does a question get closed except via the process of moderation? Maybe there's a bunch of lingo/jargon w.r.t. to the operation of this site that I'm not familiar with, and if that's confusing matters I apologize.

Comment: *"How does a question get closed except via the process of moderation?"* By *normal* users with the priviledge to vote to close. One would hope that you are familiar with the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) system by the time you have 2k reputation.

Comment: @ThomA OK, should I edit the question to say I am baffled by what the users of this are looking for?

Comment: No, that would be meta-commentary and would (likely) be removed.

Comment: So maybe it's not an excellent question. But I think the asker is getting at something that is a better question than 99% of what I see flow through this site. I.e., why do we need to recompile for different architectures?

Sure this could be researched, but that is true of everything on this site. Doesn't SO _want_ to be the place with the best answer for that question? I'm genuinely confused about what this site wants to be...

Comment: @ThomA _"One would hope..."_ Really? I've just been asking/answering questions. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: There are 1,000's of questions posted on [so] every day, @pamphlet , and not enough users curate that content; not enough poeple use their down/close vote privileges. This means that bad questions slip through the cracks and end up not being closed. The existence of other bad questions doesn't make bad questions permissible.

Comment: Yes *really*, @pamphlet . You have about 100 undeleted posts, so some understanding of how the site works (such as that it uses community curation) would be expected.

Comment: @ThomA OK, fair enough. I agree with that.

So then, is it fair to say the problem with this question is the confusion around compiling "on" vs "for", and the "intel" vs "x86" confusion? And if those were addressed, would this be a good question? Or is it essential to show research?

I guess my fundamental confusion is: if it's a good question about programming that hasn't been asked/answered on this site, does SO want the question here? Or is the instruction go elsewhere to get an answer?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do "compile a C++ program" & "compile a C++ program on an Intel processor" & "compile a C++ program on an Intel processor without using any processor specific feature" mean? Note that if the asker was actually acting in a specific way reasonably describable by those they could give relevant details of a system, input, desired output, any output & what they were running. As it is, even for whatever general category of situations they think they have in mind they happen to have written something too vague to answer. PS Posters should clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: “But isn't SO the place where people will go to do this research?” - No; It’s not. 5 minutes of research would have indicated that the output compilers create are architecture (processor) specific.

Comment: @ThomA "should I edit the question to say I am baffled by what the users of this are looking for?" "No, that would be meta-commentary" I expect that the asker here meant replacing "moderators" by (curating) "users" in this meta question, which is appropriate & which I have done, but that you thought they meant the main site question.

Comment: If I try copying and pasting your question title into a search engine, after your question and this meta question, the next results I get are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694719 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168380.

Comment: Aside from the lack of clarity, it is generally not useful to ask about hypotheticals - "in X situation, would Y happen?" Either X situation can be readily created (perhaps, by someone else) - in which case the correct approach is to **try it** (or ask/pay someone else to try it; the place for that is a discussion forum, **not** Stack Overflow) and see whether Y happens - or it cannot, in which case it does not matter.

Comment: Generally, suitable questions  for Stack Overflow are either *how-to* questions - "what situation is required for Y to happen?" - or *why* (often described as "debugging" questions; but we will not find the bug for you, you are expected to create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) questions - "I created X situation; why didn't Y happen? / Why did Z (which is not Y) happen?"

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback on this. I do regret the hyperbole I used in phrasing this (meta) question. The original SO question wasn't mine, and I have been convinced that it was not a good question for several reasons. I do (personally) think a question on why do programs need to be separately compiled for different architectures is a good (if basic) question, and wish SO had more of that kind of content. But OP's question was not that. And my championing of it was confusing and unnecessarily confrontational. Apologies and thanks to all who took the time to engage on this--it's appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The question is too unclear/unspecific in several areas.

> If we compile a C++ program on an Intel processor without using any processor specific feature. Would it run on some other company's processor without recompiling?

1. It's very unspecific. **Some other company's processor**: Should an author include a list of all available processors and state if it is likely that the program will run there? The OP certainly has something in mind when they ask. Maybe they're only asking about other desktop processors? Maybe about ones for mobile phones? Maybe some embedded system processors?
2. It's unclear if the OP really thinks that the processor **on** which a program gets compiled matters (which would be a false premise of the whole question) or if the OP actually asks about a program that is compiled **for** a specific processor.
3. Processor manufacturer != processor architecture != supported instruction set.
   Intel produces different processors with different architectures. A program that runs on an x64 intel processor might not run on an x86 intel processor, but on an x64 AMD processor.
4. The question completely ignores the problem of operating systems. A program that runs on a processor on one operating system might not run on the same processor on a different OS.